# How to Update the Record in Wizard?

Tags: odoo, wizard, odoo-12

I am using Odoo v12, I have one requirement to update the qty in wizard view. I have added two button Plus and Minus and but there is an issue with the update qty related. qty, it is not increasing [Here the image the Plus and Minus qty related](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryIdX.png).

```
@api.multi
def action_plus(self):
    for record in self:
        record.qty  = record.qty + 1
    return {"type": "set_scrollTop"}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what I found while working with per line `button` in tree view that it work's only when a record is saved before. For example, if I add a new line in the `one2many lines` in a form, the new lines button isn't yet effective until those new records are saved. You can make sure by inspecting the button on your wizard line and check if `disabled` tag is present, which is rendered from odoo for lines newly added and not yet saved.[image: Odoo Disabled Button]

Comment: But I did not write any tag such like "disabled" my button tag is <button name="action_plus" icon="fa-plus-square" type="object" style="float:right" />